# Assemblies in SQL Server keep unloading and loading again periodically

Tags: sql-server, sqlclr

SQL Server keeps loading and unloading my Assemblies, marking them as unsafe. Any ideas why it would do that.

I am attaching the log file down below.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Assemblies are being unloaded due to the exact reason stated in the log: memory pressure. There is nothing specific you can do to prevent that (i.e. no option to disable this behavior). The most you can do is reduce the chances of it happening by adding more memory and/or reducing the memory consumption of your queries and/or SQLCLR objects.

The above suggestions are not meaning that there is anything currently inefficient in either your queries or .NET code, just that if you need more memory, you either need to add more or use less of it. And if you are currently using as little as possible, then you pretty much need to add more memory.

Without seeing your .NET code, it is not possible to determine if there are any areas that could be improved. However, it is more likely that the issue is outside of your SQLCLR code. You need to determine how much memory you have and where it is being used. Try looking through this Question on DBA.StackExchange:

[SQL Server 2012 memory consumption outside the buffer pool](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/89834/sql-server-2012-memory-consumption-outside-the-buffer-pool)

Also, SQL Server is not marking the Assembly as `UNSAFE`. That is simply how you have the Assembly set. You might try altering the Assembly to instead be `EXTERNAL_ACCESS` if it really is only doing file system access operations.

Comment: How do you reduce or add memory consumption for just CLR's?

Comment: @ValK I have updated my answer, but it depends on your code. Your code could be fine, I was just saying that it is an area to look at.

Comment: Thanks. Well I think CLR code is fine. I would like to try to allocate more memory to CLR's out of all available sql memory but not sure how to do it. From reading some of the links in your post I found out that CLR memory is part of max server memory , is that true?

Comment: I am addressing that on the other question.

Comment: Also, what exactly are you trying to fix? Is there something breaking, or did you just notice this in the logs and didn't know what to think of it? From your log file, it shows that the AppDomain was there for 40 minutes before being unloaded and reloaded one second later. While not ideal, I wouldn't think that it was slowing things down. Is it?

Comment: I don't think it is slowing anything down, yet I would like to stop it or , at least, reduce the frequency of that event taking place. If there is a way, I would take advantage of it..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107077/discussion-between-val-k-and-srutzky).