# How do I reduce or add memory allocation for just CLR in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, sqlclr

I cannot reduce or add memory to CLR's. I read online that it is possible to do. How would I do it with -q option?

This question is a follow-up to:

[Assemblies in SQL Server keep unloading and loading again periodically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36158390/clrs-in-sql-server-keep-unloading-and-loading-again-periodically)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no CLR-specific memory allocation. What memory is available for SQLCLR objects depends on:

- What version of SQL Server you are on. Memory allocation changed starting in SQL Server 2012.
- What processor architecture you are on: 32 bit vs 64 bit.
- How much memory is in the server
- If there are other processes running on the server

Here are some resources to learn more about memory in relation to SQL Server:

1. [SQL Server memory - Internals (SQL Server 2005, 2008, and 2008 R2)](http://mssqlwiki.com/sqlwiki/sql-performance/basics-of-sql-server-memory-architecture/)
2. [SQL Server 2012 Memory](http://mssqlwiki.com/tag/sql-server-2012-memory-architecture/)
3. [Understanding the VAS Reservation (aka MemToLeave) in SQL Server](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/jonathan_kehayias/archive/2009/07/07/understanding-the-vas-reservation-aka-memtoleave-in-sql-server.aspx)
4. [SQL Server Memory Configuration, Determining MemToLeave Settings](http://www.johnsansom.com/sql-server-memory-configuration-determining-memtoleave-settings/)
5. [AppDomain 2 (mssqlsystemresource.dbo[runtime].1) is marked for unload due to memory pressure message in SQL Server Log](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/116688/appdomain-2-mssqlsystemresource-dboruntime-1-is-marked-for-unload-due-to-mem)
6. [Why does dm_os_memory_clerks have MEMORYCLERK_SQLCLR values on one NUMA node?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/113127/why-does-dm-os-memory-clerks-have-memoryclerk-sqlclr-values-on-one-numa-node)