# AppDomain unloaded

Tags: sql-server, memory, sql-server-2014, sqlclr

I know I have asked this question before but didn't get a good answer. My sql server 2014 keeps unloading Appdomain due to memory pressure that I think has something to do with my CLRs. I am not sure how to fix it at this point. I have already tried a lot of things. I will attach my log to this post. Thank you for your any help. [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing has changed since you first posted this same question here:

[Assemblies in SQL Server keep unloading and loading again periodically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36158390/assemblies-in-sql-server-keep-unloading-and-loading-again-periodically)

There is no way to prevent SQL Server from being able to unload any AppDomain it chooses to.

Memory Pressure means that there is not a lot of physical memory left and SQL Server greatly prefers physical ram over swap/page file. Here are things to look at:

1. Review your SQLCLR code. Are you properly closing disposable objects? Are you storing a lot of things in memory? Why are your Assemblies marked as `UNSAFE`? Is it because you are storing data in static variables? Are you using .NET classes that have memory leaks and hence are prevented from being used in `SAFE` and `EXTERNAL_ACCESS` Assemblies (e.g. using `TimeZoneInfo` to convert `DATETIME` values between two TimeZoneIDs)?
2. How much memory is available on the server even when the SQLCLR code isn't running? Is SQL Server configured to use enough system memory (i.e. check the Max Server Memory setting).
3. Are there other applications / processes running on the OS besides SQL Server? If so, they can be taking up physical memory that should be going to SQL Server.